# How to repair a laminate countertop?

Tags: home

I have a laminate countertop and it is chipped a little bit. I wanted to know if you have any trick to repair it. I don't have any images but it'hs this kind of [high pressure laminate](http://www.formica.com/en/ca/products/formica-laminate-home#swatchesTab).

Can someone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Fixing laminate counter-tops (e.g. Formica©) may be difficult in that the repair might not blend well with the surrounding surface and in that it might not adhere well. There are commercial products such as [Fix-a-Chip](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Fix-a-Chip-Counter-Desktop-Repair-As-Seen-on-TV/174267808) and [ReStor-it Quick20 Fix-A-Chip Repair Kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004DJ56IK), but read the review before purchasing - the products I saw often were shipped damaged and made poor repairs.

If you have a scrap of the old laminate, you can try grinding it to a powder and mixing into a clear epoxy. Surface preparation is essential: after cleaning with water and detergent, a bit of sanding to abrade the surface and then final wipe with acetone will help the patch to adhere. Sand the dried patch to match the level and finish of the surrounding material with progressively finer grades of sandpaper. Directions for edge repair can be found [online](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/repair-chipped-formica-counter-71580.html).

[Formica suggests that large chips or burns be cut out](http://www.formica.com/en/us/advice-and-ideas/tips--how-to-repair-burn-marks-on-laminate) and replaced with a cutting board or trivet. I've sanded burnt spots level and covered them with ceramic tile, adhered with tile mastic or flexible grout.